# MySQL Service allow local connections through hosts.allow

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, debian

I have my hosts.deny set up as `ALL: ALL` but when I do this I can't seem to allow MySQL in hosts.allow. I need to be able to access MySQL just on the local network.

I've tried:

```
mysql: LOCAL
mysqld: LOCAL
```

and as a last resort:

```
mysql: ALL
mysqld: ALL
```

But I just get a socket connection error on those local device when trying to connect. I'm assuming I'm in the right area, but on the wrong road...

Comment: What are you trying to do? There are generally better methods than TCP wrappers for whatever it is.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Basically have various Python scripts inserting to a MySQL database on a (Ubuntu) server, so just need to allow local connections to the MySQL databasen - have separate users in MySQL, but being unable to use hosts.allow with MySQL means that I can't do ALL: ALL in hosts.deny

Comment: Sounds like you need to be configuring a firewall. TCP wrappers is ancient and crusty and was invented long before hosts had firewalls.

Comment: Try to give the loopback address?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm using iptables too, does that make denyhosts redundant and pointless?

Comment: @toxboi How do I do that? (Sorry, bit new to this!)

Comment: Um, yes. If you actually have a firewall there's no point to TCP wrappers.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Ah brill! Probably got quite a bit on my server that's useless.. I'll make sure my firewall rules are all good and drop the denyhosts then..!

Comment: There are some useful things you can do with tcpwrappers that you can't with iptables and vice versa. Did you check if your system was able to resolve 'mysql' to a port number?